# Magento1: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, product-images, foreign-key-constraint

getting the error while uploading the media files to the products, I have tried repairing the tables and also tried increasing the INT value in table structure still giving the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (db-4.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value, CONSTRAINTFK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_IDFOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCEScore_store(store_id) ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTOcatalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value(value_id,store_id,label,position,disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Is it fine to truncate the media table and then run the re-indexer or it will loose all the media?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code, that throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the after debugging and digging into the deep found that the MYSQL was doing some issues it was not communicating well with the Application, So just restart the service and also increased the memory limit as well it resolved the issue now it is working fine.